# Read remote DBF database file using dbase_open() in php?

Tags: php, foxpro, dbf

How can I use a .dbf file which is on one network system using `dbase_open()` in php?

I could do it if the file is in the system itself by just specifying the path of the .dbf file.

I have no idea how to access the file from a remote system.

Comment: Google would seem to indicate you can't. Along with a load of people blaming Windows\FoxPro when of course it's a PHP problem.